# Modded Minecraft error: No such method?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

When loading my first mod I am getting the following error:

> Error: cpw.mods.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.haxium.basicmod.obsidian.armor.ItemObsidianPickaxe.setTextureName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lnet/minecraft/item/Item;
>   I also get the same error with ItemObsidianPickaxe.setUnlocalizedName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lnet/minecraft/item/Item;

Does anyone have any ideas why?

Here is the ItemObisidianPickaxe code:

```
package com.haxium.basicmod.obsidian.armor;

import net.minecraft.item.ItemPickaxe;
import com.haxium.basicmod.obsidian.armor.*;

public class ItemObsidianPickaxe extends ItemPickaxe {
    public ItemObsidianPickaxe(ToolMaterial material, String name) {
        super(material);
        setUnlocalizedName("obsidian_armor_" + name);
        setTextureName("obsidian_armor:" + name);
    }
}
```

Link to crash log: https://pastebin.com/Um74Reps

Comment: How did you compile your mod?

Comment: `@Override` the setTextureName()

Answer (score 0):

Check ***ItemPickaxe*** Class, because there you should have defined ***setTextureName***. It could be that it is a protected method and is not accessible from outside of inheritance Or it doesn't have at all that method.

Comment: setTextureName is inherited from ItemPickaxe though.

Comment: Should ItemObsidianPickaxe implement ItemPickaxe?

Comment: The method modifier is public.

Comment: The code that is my original post is what I have. Should I try implementing ItemPickaxe?

Comment: I am unable to find the ItemPickaxe.java file. I will keep looking

Comment: Where are defined this methods ? setUnlocalizedName(String); setTextureName(String);

Comment: You don't have those methods defined there. Maybe they are in: net.minecraft.item.ItemTool ?  The idea is that you don't have those methods defined in ItemObsidianPickaxe  or in any superclassess you showed until now.

Comment: Thats a strong possibility.

Comment: You said that method modifier is public, from where you took that info ?

Comment: Nevermind. Even importing ItemTool didn't fix the error

Comment: ONE MORE TIME show/check the code where are defined methods: setTextureName(String) and setUnlocalizedName(String) , otherwise you will not be able to fix the problem. If they are not defined it means you should define them.

Comment: I get it now. I have to find the class where these are defined. I will work on it

Comment: I found an article saying to call the methods like this: this.setTextureName and this.setUnlocalizedName with no luck. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Declare those methods in your ItemPickaxe.java class. But you should also create the body for those methods so you have to create the logic that is behind that methods. This will solve the issue.